Emulator not working in VS Code which working with flutter
The emulator stays in the taskbar

The error screen

I am trying to open emulator in VS code it doesn't open up. It just flashes in the screen in the taskbar but didn't shows on my screen. I use it my opening Android Studio in background. I have tried to delete all the emulators and created new one but there's nothing changed.

Did you already try to end task the emulator from task manager? and please share your flutter doctor
